# c++ How to assign multiple numbers to multiple variables using one user input

Tags: c++11

What I have right now is:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

User Input is :  4 / 5 / 6

how do I assign 4 to a, 5 to b and 6 to c, given that there are "/" between the numbers in addition to the white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to solve this problem would be to use a `char` variable for reading the '/' characters.

So you could use:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

char slash;

cin >> a >> slash >> b >> slash >> c;
```

Alternatively, you could look into `scanf` provided by `stdio.h` and then rather than using `cin` you could write:

```
scanf("%i / %i / %i", &a, &b, &c);
```